# In Android AppCompatActivity, can I have an abstract method being implemented by each subclass that extends BaseActivity?

Tags: java, android, hierarchy

Say I have a base class, `BaseActivity`, which extends `AppCompatActivity`. Inside `BaseActivity`, I have:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected abstract void setUp();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setUp();
    }
}
```

Then all my `Activity` classes extend `BaseActivity`, as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private ActivityMainBinding mBinding;
    private FeedTopicsFragment mFeedTopicsFragment;
    private UserDiscussionsFragment mUserDiscussionsFragment;
    private UserConversationsFragment mUserConversationsFragment;
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void setUp() {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_main);
        String signedInUserId = SessionPersistor.getSignedInUserId();
        if (signedInUserId == null) {
            NavigationHelper.goToSignInUserActivity(this);
            return;
        }
        setSupportActionBar(mBinding.activityMainAppbar);
        // do other stuff to mBinding etc, all at the beginning of onCreate
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadData();   
    }
}
```

Is this implementation even possible? I want to save the hassle of me remembering to call `setUp` each time, since for each activity it's the same: in onCreate, I have to setup the views, etc. Is this going to throw exception because `setUp` is an abstract method but it's being called in `BaseActivity` onCreate, but at the time when `setUp` is being called from `MainActivity`, `setUp` is already implemented in `MainActivity`, just that the order when `setUp` is being called is defined in the `BaseActivity` `onCreate` method?

Comment: what is the problem when you run the above code?

Comment: there is no error, i'm just asking if this is bad practice

Comment: no. i don't see anything wrong with the approach

Comment: Everything is OK, good use of polymorphism

Answer (score 0):

you can call `setup` from `onCreate` of BaseActivity.